Getting Sum of Weights used in `ee.Reducer.mean()` - Google Earth Engine
I am running code to get the mean of an image (of crop yields) for a series of polygons (farms) on Google Earth Engine (GEE). For that, I am using ee.Reducer.mean(). However, it might be the case that I get a mean for a given farm even if it does not truly contain the crops shown in my image. For example, maybe farm A grows crop A, but not a neighbouring farm B. Because gridcells of crop yields in my image are 30x30m, it might be the case that a small fraction of one of these gridcells intersects with farm B. However, if the intersection is large enough (more than 0.5% of the area of the gridcell, from what I gathered in GEE's documentation), ee.Reducer.mean() would still consider it for calculating the mean and without further analysis it would seem like farm B grows crop A.
I tried correcting for this by checking how many non-null inputs (gridcells) are going into ee.Reducer.mean() for different farms. I have done so using ee.Reducer.count(). However, this reducer only returns integer numbers (the number of inputs, indeed). However, my goal was to get the sum of percentages of different inputs that go into a given ee.Reducer.mean(). For instance, if a mean is calculated with 3% of the area of gridcell A and 60% of the area of gridcell B, I would like to get 0.63 as my output. How can I do that? Alternatively, could I do this directly on ee.Reducer.mean() by considering the sum of the weights used and filtering based on it?
Thanks for your help!
